# Light Table won't start on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, lighttable

I'm trying to start Light Table on Windows 7 and so far nothing. I followed the instructions on [the official github page](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable) and I've only been able to get the main window to display the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build from source for a particular reason? There are binaries on the light table website: http://www.lighttable.com/

Comment: I just followed the instructions on the github page. I'm not trying to build it from source since the instructions say to use the dll and exe files from the latest official build.

Comment: @KRTac I see what you're saying. I just tried it myself, with the same results, so there must be a bug in the current master. That's likely intended for contributors; if all you want is to use it, your best bet is the current stable off of their main site, which is currently working.